# foldl operation in sml

Tags: sml

I would appreciate if someone could guide me here, I really want to understand what I did wrong and why?

This is my code:

```
fun get_longest xs = foldl((fn (x ,y ) => if  String.size x >= String.size y then x
else y),[],xs)
```

My function should take a list of strings and return the longest string; if the list is empty, just `return []`.

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: 'Z * 'Y -> 'Y
  operand:         (string * string -> string) * int * 'X
  in expression:
  foldl ((fn (<pat>,<pat>) => if <exp> then <exp> else <exp>),0,xs)

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the signature of [foldl](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html):

```
val foldl : ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
```

You can see that your function should have the form

```
fun get_longest xs = foldl foo acc xs
```

where `foo` is the function applies on an element and an accumulator and `acc` is the initial accumulator.

**Hints:**

1. Since `get_longest` returns a `string`, the accumulator should have type `string`. Your job is to find out a suitable string to fill in. Note that the value `[]` you want here doesn't make sense.
2. `xs` is a `string list`, your `foo` function should have type `string * string -> string`. Now you have to replace `foo` by an appropriate anonymous function.

Answer (score 4):

`foldl` is a curried functions, it's type is `('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b`. Therefore it should be called as `foldl f s xs`. You're calling it as `foldl (f, s, xs)`. That's wrong because it calls `foldl` with a tuple as its argument and `foldl` does not expect a tuple. If it did, its type would be `('a * 'b -> 'b) * 'b * 'a list -> 'b`.